# Getting value from a sql result set using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a vb.net application in which `Sql` result set is returning value. 
values are of multiple rows.

```
"abc" 1000 "sdr" 12 
"abv" 2100 "asas" 25
```

i want to get the  value of each `row- 3rd column`, 
how can i get it using vb.net

Comment: Post your piece of code on which you are retrieving the results.

Comment: I didn't have the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Dim dt as DataTable = GetResultSetFromSQL()
System.Diagnostic.Debug.Print(dt.Rows(0).Item(2))
System.Diagnostic.Debug.Print(dt.Rows(1).Item(2))
```

You should get this in Output window:

```
sdr
asas
```

It is just an example to give you an starter, on saving the result set of sql in `DataTable` object and how to retrieve specific rows/columns from it.

Hope it helps!

**EDIT:**

Have a look at this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It shows how to handle this recordset in details.

Perhaps this may help: (untested)

```
While !myRecordset.EOF

temp = myRecordset.FieldValue(3)
myRecordset.MoveNext()

End While
```

Comment: ok then in which object do you get your result set ? DataSet ? or what else ?

Comment: myRecordset = conn.Execute("select * from employees")  temp = myRecordset.FieldValue(3) this is giving the value of a 3rd cell i want to get the value of 3rd column of all the rows. so i want to loop trough the rows how to do it

Comment: i tried this already. am getting error like Public member 'EOF' on type 'IRecordset' not found.

Comment: What is the type of `myRecordset` ?